# Euler's Method for n steps

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Write y for the solution to $y' = 2x$ with $y(0) = 0$. What is
y(1)? What is the Euler approximation for y(1), using 2 equal steps? 3 equal steps? What
about n steps, where n can now be any natural number? (It will be useful to know that
$1 + 2 + · · · + (n − 1) = n(n − 1)/2.)$ As $ n → ∞$, these approximations should converge to
$y(1)$. Do they?

I know that $y = x^2$ since $y'=2x$. With that I just preformed the Eulers steps and put them in a table format. I understand how to get the values with an actual number, but I am struggling for a general case of n steps. I can tell that as n increases then the solution is going to go to $y(1)=1$ by inspection.

I just can't tie in the $1 + 2 + · · · + (n − 1) = n(n − 1)/2.)$ As $ n → ∞$ relation for the problem. I feel it has something to do with the fact that $h=1/n$

[image: Solution to first two conditions.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If we let $x_{k,n} = \frac{k}{n}$ and $y_{k,n}$ be the Euler approximation at $x_{k,n}$ when using $n$ steps, then we have
$$ y_{k+1,n} - y_{k,n} = (2x_{k,n})\frac{1}{n} = \frac{2k}{n^2}. $$
Note that $y_{0,n}=0$ and $y_{n,n}$ is the Euler approximation for $y(1)$ using $n$ steps. We then have
$$ y_{n,n} = y_{n,n} - y_{0,n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{(y_{k+1,n}-y_{k,n})} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{2k}{n^2}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand the buildup to the formula and where the summation comes from. I am a little rusty though on how to calculate the final summation. My calculus 2 skills have faded a bit with time. I think a small kick in the direction of how to solve it will do me right, if you can provide that.

Comment: Sure. So you can factor $\frac{2}{n^2}$ out from every term in the sum, leaving you with $\frac{2}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{k}$, and the hint provided in your question tells you what the value of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{k}$ is. If you don't remember how to prove the statement in the hint, you can look up "sum of first $n$ natural numbers" or something similar.